# Order by DATE_FORMAT not working properly

Tags: mysql, date-format

```
SELECT  SUBSTR(`filename`, 1, 10) as filedate, `filename`, `filepath`
FROM  `files`  
WHERE `filepath` LIKE 'sites/default/files/news/%' 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(filedate,'%m.%d.%Y') ASC
```

the file name incluedes the date in the first 10 characters ex. 06.28.2013-Title_of_file
so I grab the substring and set it as filedate, filter with WHERE LIKE

Then I try and order by the date using date_format, but when I run query it does not order correctly.

Do I have to convert it to date format? If so then how do I do that within SQL?

Comment: Can you show more of your sample rows. Do you have a column of date type or is the filename prefix all you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(`filename`, 1, 10),'%m.%d.%Y') as filedate, `filename`, `filepath`
FROM  `files`  
WHERE `filepath` LIKE 'sites/default/files/news/%' 
ORDER BY filedate ASC
```

This will convert the stripped string into a `DATE` object.

Answer (score 0):

You should just order by filedate. **Regardless of the format of the date it is still the same date and time**. `DATE_FORMAT` returns a formated date not a column.

Comment: - `filedate` is a derived field.

Comment: you can order by derived fields. Though if I had noticed I would have done what DevlshOne did.

Comment: You're missing the point. `fielddate` is not a date column as you assumed and therefore `DATE_FORMAT()` does nothing.